# Android app crashing after Zen Desk integration

Tags: android, integration, zendesk

I added the following code to my I Android app's onCreate method:

```
ZendeskConfig.INSTANCE.init(this, "https://abc.zendesk.com",
    "1900ecb********7f4d6e5b9********b56933********ce", 
    "mobile_sdk_client_*******43de4********");
Identity identity = new AnonymousIdentity.Builder().withNameIdentifier("Generic").build();

ZendeskConfig.INSTANCE.setIdentity(identity);
```

I added the following to my button click handler:

```
new SupportActivity.Builder().show(Welcome.this);
```

Now my app crashes with the following error

when I click the button

> com.zendesk.sdk.storage.SdkStorage.INSTANCE
>
> at
>   com.zendesk.sdk.support.SupportActivity.onCreate(SupportActivity.java:152)

I created a new account on ZenDesk to test the issue but it crashes there too.

Comment: Formatted code and error messages, improved flow and diction.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/version_information

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Can you post the full stracktrace?